# How to write custom type to accept extended types

Tags: typescript

I have had trouble while implementing a custom type for extension types. I have something like:

```
export interface StateModel extends Resp1Model, Resp2Model{}
```

I need something very similar to built-in Typescript type ***Partial***. But instead of my custom type being key of the model, it should be extended by the model. I've tried to implement my type as this:

```
type Inside<P, T> = T extends P ? P : undefined;
```

but this is not what I want. In this implementation I have to pass the sub-types inside to my custom type. So I have to do this:

```
let some: Inside<Resp1Model, StateModel> = someVariable as Resp1Model;
let someOther: Inside<Resp2Model, StateModel> = someVariable as Resp2Model;
```

But instead, I would like to accept `anything` that is extended by given model. So I basically try to do:

```
let some: Inside<StateModel> = someVariable as Resp2Model;
let someOther: Inside<StateModel> = someVariable as Resp1Model;
```

How can I refactor Inside type to achieve this?

I'm attaching a playground link [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQM4AcCMBZAewBMIAbAbwChkbk4AuZDMKUAc0oF9LLRJZEKdNgBMhEhWq0ARvRABXALbToXHn2jwkyAMpg4kcWWQQAHpBBEMaTLiOkANDdH3y3SmACeWFAEkQGMAkADwACk4AKgB8yAC8yBEm5hCW1qHIAPzI6YzylhAwoBBEANw8pBBgTASKEARgABbQcchUtHSMAOQ4nWqUFVUYNRCM-oEhwnbEZE56BhD2MfFDtfVNUGWUCAQBBBUAdKQEbAAUKxAAlDyUAPQ3yL7IAO4E8qREyKTAANYoYATIbYgABu0CqYyCfwBjWAGHoPDun0q1VWjWgjEm+GmpBaVER7QYyG6vUR7kRAxRIweAUhwTmhmxS0pa2gJSAA). Thanks for any help.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here but I think `Partial<StateModel>` is actually the type you are looking for. I can't see what type information `Inside<StateModel>` could actually return that would make it more expressive. All it says is that the object has either some or all of the properties of `StateModel`, with no specific properties defined, which is exactly what `Partial` would tell you.

Comment: @lawrence-witt, No, I don't think so. Because when creating new variable it's not a problem. For example try to make the assignment : someother = some;  at the end of the attached playground file. With custom Inside it's possible but with Partial it's not.

Comment: I guess the right solution to this is type casting instead of creating generics.

Answer (score 2):

Am I understating you correctly, you want `Inside<T>` to return all interfaces that `T` have extended in its definition?

If that's the case, do you have the option of changing the definition of `StateModel` from an interface to a type alias, like this:

```
type StateModel = Resp1Model | Resp2Model
```

Because then you could simply use `StateModel` straight up. No `Inside<T>` needed.

```
interface Resp1Model{
    a: string
}

interface Resp2Model{
    b: number
}

type StateModel = (
    | Resp1Model
    | Resp2Model
);

let someother = {
    a: '1'
}

let some: StateModel = someother;

someother = some;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQM4AcCMBZAewBMIAbAbwChkbk4AuZDMKUAc0oF9LLRJZEKdNgBMhEhWq0ARvRABXALbToXHmACeWFAGUwcSOLLIAvMgAUUmgB80mXEdJXkt4VjHEylAJQBudVooAJIgGMAkADwACgA0yAAqAHymCcgQAB6QIEQYyFHIAPx5yIzy2RAwoBBE-pSkEGBMBIoQBGAAFtApVLR0jADkOP1qdQ1NLYx6BhCOKRjNrR3QtQgEoQT1AHSkBGzm8y3ePAeLnVBzC-5AA)

Comment: I guess type casting is the good practice too.